# Two VirtualComputers. I have one for testing and connecting on second one LDAPServer

Tags: ldap, connection, virtual

I already have two virtual machines which we got in school. First one is named SimpleArbiter to implement test on it and the other is LDAPServer.

On LDAPServer i have to install server LDAP. It must have domain DC=thalia-62, DC=kpov, DC=lusy, DC=fri, DC=uni-lj, DC=si

Next i have to make new enter code hereusers:
CN=majazmeda48,ou=Users,DC=thalia-62,DC=kpov,DC=lusy,DC=fri,DC=uni-lj,DC=si

with pass: Dea8OF

and user:
CN=rokkolar15,ou=Users,DC=thalia-62,DC=kpov,DC=lusy,DC=fri,DC=uni-lj,DC=si 
with pass iF7XyX

Next step is to make sure that i can connect from SimpleArbiter on LDAPServer. If i can connect as rokkolar15 with pass iF7XyX, must server enable changing data for object CN=majazmeda48,ou=Users,DC=thalia-62,DC=kpov,DC=lusy,DC=fri,DC=uni-lj,DC=si and enable making new objects in DC=thalia-62,DC=kpov,DC=lusy,DC=fri,DC=uni-lj,DC=si

```
CN = Common Name
OU = Organizational Unit
DC = Domain Component
```

Last step is to create a program on SimpleArbiter, which will with help of ldapsearch gave us back properties of children that random object has in thalia-62.kpov.lusy.fri.uni-lj.si. 
Name of object(CN) must program get as first argument.

Comment: This post is lacking a question mark. What exactly is the problem you need help solving?

Comment: I need a walkthrough how to do this things..from the beginning...

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: It is an assigment for not doing the last homework right :D but this is harder :S

Comment: Please provide more information about the system environment running on the virtual machine. What operating system are you running (w/ exact version). What LDAP server software are you attempting to configure?

Comment: I have to use Linux Debian 4.6.3-14 for both. They are premade but its all basic. Like cmd. No interface or anything...

Comment: And this for server:
apt-get install ldap-utils.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Setting up an OpenLDAP server on Debian Linux](https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/OpenLDAPSetup)

[Configuring LDAP via command line](https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/LDAPUtils)

If you have a PHP-enabled web server installed, and prefer doing configuration via a GUI, you can use [PhpLdapAdmin](https://wiki.debian.org/PhpLdapAdmin) instead.

Once you've configured the client correctly, you can write a Bash script to query LDAP information from the LDAPServer using the [ldapsearch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapsearch) command.

Once you've made a concerted effort to accomplish these things by yourself, feel free to post a more specific question about any problems you encounter, and post a link to the new question in the comments.

Comment: Well thanks for everything but i told you i don't have the knowledge to do this thing.:S

Comment: I don't understand what you expected us to do for you then? If you don't have the ability to read and learn on your own, then you should seriously consider discussing the situation with your teacher and/or finding a tutor to help you out in person. Short of doing your homework for you and sending you the virtual machines, what else can I do to help you succeed!? **All** of the information you need to complete your assignment can be found in pages linked above. Have you read them yet?

Comment: Hi again. 
I now did a lot of things with your guieds. But now i need help how to connect from one virtual computer to another and be able to change user settings that are stored on the other computer...

Comment: Do they both have network adapters on the same (virtual) network? Usually sshd is running by default on most Linux distros, so you could try to SSH into it. e.g. `ssh username@LDAPServer -p` when it prompts for identity type `yes` and provide your password. If you get a DNS name resolution error, use the ip address instead `ssh username@12.34.56.78 -p`. If you get a timeout, SSH daemon is probably not running, try `service sshd restart` on the server.

Comment: Hello again. I have to use ldapsearch to connect with computer on which ldap server is configured. And it says that if i connect to ldap server with "example user" and if i then write the right password i can be able to modify that user settings. So if you know how to do this please...Googling around a lot but can't find how to connect with explicit user...

Comment: `ldapsearch` is a search tool; you cannot modify the LDAP database with this tool. You must use `ldapmodify` for that. Look at the examples here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldapmodify

Comment: This are instructions:
In case that client connects with user "exampleuser" and password "pass" let server enable changing data for that object.